# Вывести значения элемента, зная ключ массива

Tags: php

Делаю:

```
print_r($keynomerlist);
```

Получаю: `

```
Array ( ['name'] => Название: ['area'] => Площадь (м2) ['smallpeople'] => 4 ['bigpeople'] => 2 ['description'] => 321 ['addPhotos'] => Array ( [0] => img-9ea69.jpg ) )`
```

Но если пытаться вывести так:

```
echo $keynomerlist['area'];
```

Ничего не показывается. Почему?

Comment: попробуйте `echo $keynomerlist[1];` вместо `echo $keynomerlist['area'];` может получится)

Comment: Можно посмотреть полный код?

Comment: Полноценный отсутствует. Получаем данные из формы, в массив $keynomerlist и пытаемся их записать. Но обратиться не получается.

Comment: не помешало бы посмотреть! ибо

    $list = array(
    'a' => 'A',
    'b' => 'B'
    );
    
    echo $list['a'] . $list['b'];

Работет без проблем!

Comment: Я знаю что оно работает без проблем :)
Я скопировал свои шаги и что получается.

Comment: Тогда могу только высказать предположение, что у вас работает какой-то партизан, пишущий ключи массивов русскими буквами: 'аrea'.

Comment: Точно нет :) Пишу я, и точно английскими. И остальные ключи тоже не работают.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Заинтересовали, потестил код)

```
print_r(array('a'=>'b'));// Array ( [a] => b )
```

Ответ на ваш вопрос:

```
echo $keynomerlist["'area'"];
```

либо уберите кавычки из формы ;) У вас там `<input type="text" name="arrayname['area']" />`, в html надо писать `name="arrayname[area]"`

Answer (score 2):

Используй foreach. Например, так:

```
foreach($keynomerlist as $k=>$v)
{
 if ($k!=='addphotos') echo "<br>k=".$k." v=".$v;
 else {
   foreach($v['addphotos'] as $kphoto=>$vphoto {
     echo "<br>kphoto=".$kphoto." vphoto=".$vphoto;
   }
 }
}
```

Должно вывести все элементы твоего массива. Я не проверял, но теоретически должно заработать. Если что, пиши.

Comment: @yura1976, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1):

А если так:

```
echo keynomerlist[0]['area'];
```

Comment: [0] даст name по идее) но не важно)

Comment: Цифры тоже не помогли :)